# Wrong resource image using getResources().getIdentifier()

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a issue with getting correct image from drawables. 
For one image it is `public static final int sh=0x7f0200d0;`
and the second one is `public static final int sr=0x7f0200d3;`.
This issue is not for all picture only for few of them. While I had 5-7 of them there wasn't any problems, but now when I have 50 of such id I run into problem.
The name `sh` is taken from DB.

Using debugging mode checked image (number code) and both are different.
I tried to clean project, rebuild project. But didn't work. I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: To which 'both' are you referring exactly? All resource ids are auto-generated and may change every time you compile your application. Hence, you should *not* rely on them to be static (even though they are at runtime). Any attempt to store the actual int values for future use may lead to errors and/or unexpected results.

Comment: "sr" and "sh" are different images. And in R.java they  have different values, mentioned above. When i debugged they both have different  number : http://prntscr.com/8or25w and sr http://prntscr.com/8or2kl. But somehow when i click on  object which should show "sh" image it shows the other one.

Comment: why don't you use a context to get the resource instead of trying to get the identifier directly?

Comment: Could you post an a example? because i used code from example, i know what it doing and how it works :). or you thinking like context.getResources().getIdentifier(); ?

Comment: @rudis: I don't see the issue? `0x7f0200d0` == `2130837712` (first link). That second link shows no context whatsoever, so I have no idea if I'm looking at `sr` or something completely different. Nevertheless, I think your question could benefit from some code to clarify what you're currently doing, what results you get with that and what you expect it to be.

Comment: Ok for clearing all out. I havee Google Map where i want to add image to markers.  Image name "sr" or "sh" is taken from db then searched using getResources().getIdentifier. Oh, and i in rush added wrong screen shot for sr `public static final int sr=0x7f0200d3;` = [link]. (http://prntscr.com/8ozo0i). and it's all happend these lines http://prntscr.com/8ozpea and http://prntscr.com/8ozphj. The issue is that instead of "sh" image it takes sr and places it in marker.